# UBUNTU 22.04 Plex Media Server. Unable to find Media

Tags: permissions, samba, plex

Server Version#: 1.28.2.6151-914ddd2b3

Player Version#: Web 4.87.2

This is my second time getting Plex up and running on my Ubuntu machine. I’m a complete novice at Linux and setting up Plex is among the projects that I’m using the learn. After messing up the permissions setup while trying to get file sharing to work, I recently wiped and did a fresh install of Ubuntu. During this current set up, I’ve got Samba set up to manage my file sharing and got Plex installed and running. I used this guide here: https://computingforgeeks.com/install-plex-media-server-ubuntu-debian/ to get my basic install going and also set up plex as a user and group for the directory that I use to hold my media. My machine currently has two hard drives, with the one that doesn’t hold the OS as my media drive. My movies and TV shows are stored at path /media//hdd/plex. This hard drive is mounted, which I verified using gparted.

When I use the `ls -l` command on my media storage directory, I get the following output

```
USER@Ubuntu-NAME:/media/USER/hdd/plex$ ls -l
total 8
drwxrwsr-x+ 2 plex plex 4096 Jun 21 20:01 movies
drwxrwsr-x+ 4 plex plex 4096 Jun 21 19:37 tv_shows
USER@Ubuntu-NAME:/media/USER/hdd/plex$
```

You can see that I’ve created a plex group and added the plex user to that group. However, despite the multiple days work I’ve put in to try and solve this problem, I’m unable to find any media in these directories from the plex app. Is it possible that when I set up Samba for this same directory that I somehow prevented other group or users from gaining access to the directory outside the root user?

Any help would be greatly welcome, but please keep in mind that my knowledge on using and navigating Linux and Ubuntu is very rudimentary.

Comment: Sounds like this would be a good question for Plex support.

Comment: "*My movies and TV shows are stored at path /media//hdd/plex*"  That path does not match your `ls -l` output. In your Plex settings, make sure that path is accurate.

Comment: By design the only user that can traverse the /media/USER folder to get to what is under it is USER. "plex" is not "USER" so plex will never get to the subfolders. If this is an internal "drive" mount it one level up to resolve the situation: /media/hdd/plex.